# javascript map for object in object

Tags: javascript

This is example (copied from console in google chrome):

```
var obj = [
    {word: "a"},
    {word: "b"}
];
obj.map(function(i){return i.word;})
result: ["a", "b"]
```

I need to do same but for this:

```
var o = [{
    user: "a",    
    keywords: [
         {word: "a"},
         {word: "b"},
         {word: "c"}
     ]
}];
```

I need to map `keywords` in `o`. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What is your code that did not work to map `keywords` in `o`? Maybe you're closer than you think

Comment: what is desired out put??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```js
var o = [{
    user: "a",    
    keywords: [
         {word: "a"},
         {word: "b"},
         {word: "c"}
     ]
}];

var arr = [];
o.forEach(function(k){
  k.keywords.forEach(function(w){
    arr.push(w);
  });
});


document.write(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
    var o = [{
    user: "a",    
    keywords: [
         {word: "a"},
         {word: "b"},
         {word: "c"}
     ]
}];
    var words=[];
    o.map(function(i){ words.push(i.keywords);});
    console.log(words[0].map(function(i){return i.word;}));
  </script>
```